# How can I install an IP scanner for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, scanner, ip

I simply need a way to install a subnet IP scanner so I can see which devices are connected.

In searching around I have found a lot of old web pages that talk about changing repositories to get angry IP scanner, but I do not want to change my repositories for any reason.  Plus, these pages all are for older versions.

There is an arp command but it is not exhaustive.  arp -a does not show the entire subnet; just connections from a single machine.

I never did find a clone of Advanced IP scanner.

So the question is in the title:  **How can I install an IP scanner for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?**

Comment: Note the warnings below.  But they are great tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two that work reasonably well with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The first one, arp-scan, accomplished the primary goal of ennumerating devices.  The second one, nmap, is much more versatile and gives a quick picture of the services available from each device.

1)  arp-scan

Installation is easy:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
```

It has a ton of options, which can be seen here:

```
sudo arp-scan --help
```

For basic enumeration, to scan my "local" net, is:

```
sudo arp-scan -l | sort
```

Which results in a very basic display which shows each device including IP address, MAC address and manufacturer of the interface.  It also showed "dup" responses for some of the addresses.

2) nmap

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

To run a Fast scan, which lists devices and shows open ports

```
nmap -F 192.168.8.1-254
```

The result is a fairly complete list of devices and open ports.

Here is a handy [NMAP Cheat Sheet](https://hackertarget.com/nmap-cheatsheet-a-quick-reference-guide/) to see some of the ways to use nmap.

---

I am surprised neither is installed by default in Ubuntu 16.04, but it is quick and easy to make both of them work.

Comment: Anyway be careful with both! Scanning (accidentally or not) outside of your local/private network is assumed to be a network attack and will be punished.

Comment: So noted, @derHugo.  Thank you for the reminder.  This is a good warning to have on the database.  ---->  Folks, get what he is saying here:  Walking down the street checking people's front doors to see if they are locked or looking to see if their windows are open can be considered a hostile act.  <------

Comment: And for those who are curious, YES, Google has a waiver.  At this point it would probably not be legal to set up your own web crawler.  Trust me that you don't have the resources to fight a test case.  And there are some in progress already.  Here is an interesting analysis on the subject:  https://benbernardblog.com/web-scraping-and-crawling-are-perfectly-legal-right/

Comment: On the upside, nmap showed me that I had a few issues to deal with. Ports that shouldn't have been open, like 21, 80, 8080. I used the tools lsof -i tcp:80 and netstat -plunt to figure out what was causing them and was able to reduce my internal open ports to two I use: 22 for ssh and one other for RDP. No SMB here at all. Great tool.  Mind you, I am behind a physical name-brand firewall with just two rules, and two layers of routers here.  This subnet is critical to the solar power station.  Good practice means at least 3 layers all of different brands, with one being a real firewall.